# yii2: Show label instead of value for boolean checkbox

Tags: php, yii2

I have created a check-box input as type Boolean for storing values as dishcharged - checked or unchecked. Checked will store 1 and unchecked will store 0.

Now I want to show the label as **Yes** or **No** for value 1 and 0 in grid-view and view. How can achieve that.

my _form.php code is like

```
$form->field($model, 'discharged')->checkBox(['label' => 'Discharged', 
'uncheck' => '0', 'checked' => '1'])
```

I have tried like

```
[
'attribute'=>'discharged',
'value'=> ['checked'=>'Yes','unchecked=>'no']
],
```

but doesn't look like the correct syntax.

Thanks.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

As arogachev said, you should use boolean formatter :

```
'discharged:boolean',
```

http://www.yiiframework.com/doc-2.0/guide-output-formatter.html

http://www.yiiframework.com/doc-2.0/yii-i18n-formatter.html#asBoolean()-detail

Or you could add a `getDischargedLabel()` function in your model :

```
public function getDischargedLabel()
{
    return $this->discharged ? 'Yes' : 'No';
}
```

And in your gridview :

```
[
    'attribute'=>'discharged',
    'value'=> 'dischargedLabel',
],
```

Answer (score 9):

**First option:**

```
[
    'attribute' => 'discharged',
    'format' => 'boolean',
],
```

or shortcut:

```
'discharged:boolean',
```

This does not require additional methods in your model and writing text labels (it will be set automatically depending on language in your config).

See more details [here](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc-2.0/yii-grid-datacolumn.html#$format-detail).

**Second option:**

Instead of writing additional method in model you can just pass closure to `value`.
You can check details [here](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc-2.0/yii-grid-datacolumn.html#$value-detail).

```
[
    'attribute' => 'discharged',
    'value' => function ($model) {
        return $model->discharged ? 'Yes' : 'No';
    },
],
```

Comment: @arogachev This is much simpler

Comment: yes, and you just need 'discharged:boolean' as columns definition

Comment: Yes, forgot to mention available shortcut.

Comment: Pawan : you can accept this answer instead of mine :-)

Comment: Should be $model->discharged instead of $this->discharged .

Answer (score 3):

If you consistently display booleans the same way in your app, you can also define a global boolean formatter:

```
$config = [
        'formatter' => [
          'class' => 'yii\i18n\Formatter',
          'booleanFormat' => ['<span class="glyphicon glyphicon-remove"></span> no', '<span class="glyphicon glyphicon-ok"></span> Yes'],
        ],
    ];
```

Then add your column:

```
'discharged:boolean',
```