# Changing value of an attribute in DetailView widget

Tags: yii2, detailview

I have a table named Play and I'm showing details of each record in Yii2 detail view widget. I have an attribute in that table `recurring` which is of type tinyint, it can be 0 or 1. But I don't want to view it as a number, instead i want to display `yes` or `no` based on the value (0 or 1).

I'm trying to change that with a function in detailview widget but I'm getting an error: `Object of class Closure could not be converted to string`

My detail view code:

```
 <?= DetailView::widget([
    'model' => $model,
    'attributes' => [
        'name',
        'max_people_count',
        'type',
        [
             'attribute' => 'recurring',
             'format'=>'raw',
             'value'=> function ($model) {
                        if($model->recurring == 1)
                        {

                            return 'yes';

                        } 
                        else {
                        return 'no';
                        }
                      },
        ],
        'day',
        'time',
        ...
```

Any help would be appreciated !

Comment: Taken from a similar question: [Closures in DetailView](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39266846/assigning-function-to-value-attribute-in-details-view-yii2/39299638#39299638)

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Try

```
'value' => $model->recurring == 1 ? 'yes' : 'no'
```

Answer (score 15):

Unlike `GridView` which processes a set of models, `DetailView` processes just one. So there is no need for using closure since `$model` is the only one model for display and available in view as variable.

You can definitely use [solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28300023/changing-value-of-an-attribute-in-detailview-widget/28300593#28300593) suggested by **rkm**, but there is more simple option.

By the way you can simplify condition a bit since the allowed values are only `0` and `1`:

```
'value' => $model->recurring ? 'yes' : 'no'
```

If you only want to display value as boolean, you can add formatter suffix with colon:

```
'recurring:boolean',
```

`'format' => 'raw'` is redundant here because it's just text without html.

If you want add more options, you can use this:

```
[
    'attribute' => 'recurring',
    'format' => 'boolean',    
    // Other options
],
```

Using formatter is more flexible approach because these labels will be generated depending on application language set in config.

Official documentation:

- [DetailView $attributes property](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc-2.0/yii-widgets-detailview.html#$attributes-detail)
- [Formatter class](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc-2.0/yii-i18n-formatter.html)
- [Formatter asBoolean() method](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc-2.0/yii-i18n-formatter.html#asBoolean%28%29-detail)

See also [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27354627/yii2-show-label-instead-of-value-for-boolean-checkbox), it's quite similar to yours.

Comment: This is also very useful since i will be making this application in many languages, thanks !