# Assigning function to value attribute in details view yii2

Tags: php, yii2, yii2-advanced-app, detailview

I am trying to assign a value of a function to 'value' in DetailView. But when I try that I get the error "Object of class Closure could not be converted to string"

I tried returning the value of the function by assigning it to another variable too but still the same error.

Can someone help me figure it out please?

```
 <?= DetailView::widget([
    'model' => $model,
    'attributes' => [
        'Task_ID',
        'Task_Title',
        'Description',
        'projects.project_name', //display project name instead of project id
       // 'Assign_task_to',
        //'tasksemp.Employee_ID',
        [
            'attribute' => 'Assign_task_to',
            'format' => 'raw',

            $data = function ($model) {
                $assignEmpModel = Tasksemp::find()->where(['Task_ID' => $model->Task_ID])->all(); //get all the rows with teh same task_id
                $employes = ''; //empty string
                foreach ( $assignEmpModel as $employee ) {
                    $emp = Employee::find()->where(['Employee_ID'=>$employee->Employee_ID])->one(); //get all the employee_id 
                    $name = $emp['employee_name']; //get the employee_name from the employees table
                    $employes .= ' '.$name.', '; //concatenate the names.
                }
            //  return implode(', ',$employes);
            //return $employes;
            },
            'value' => $data,
        ],
        'start_date',
        'due_date',
        'priotiy_level',
        'upload_documents',
    ],
]) ?>
```

I have tried assigning the function to a variable $data but doesn't work.

I have tried assigning the function directly to the value as well but same error.

```
[
            'attribute' => 'Assign_task_to',
            'format' => 'raw',
            'value' => function ($model) {   //<----- ERROR HERE!
                $assignEmpModel = Tasksemp::find()->where(['Task_ID' => $model->Task_ID])->all(); //get all the rows with teh same task_id
                $employes = ''; //empty string
                foreach ( $assignEmpModel as $employee ) {
                    $emp = Employee::find()->where(['Employee_ID'=>$employee->Employee_ID])->one(); //get all the employee_id 
                    $name = $emp['employee_name']; //get the employee_name from the employees table
                    $employes .= ' '.$name.', '; //concatenate the names.

                }
                return $employes;
            },
      ],
```

Tried Bizley's solution like this:

```
<?php $assignEmpModel = Tasksemp::find()->where(['Task_ID' => $model->Task_ID])->all(); //get all the rows with teh same task_id
                $employes = ''; //empty string
                foreach ( $assignEmpModel as $employee ) {
                    $emp = Employee::find()->where(['Employee_ID'=>$employee->Employee_ID])->one(); //get all the employee_id 
                    $name = $emp['employee_name']; //get the employee_name from the employees table
                    $employes .= ' '.$name.', '; //concatenate the names.
?>

<?=  DetailView::widget([
    'model' => $model,
    'attributes' => [
        'Task_ID',
        'Task_Title',
        'Description',
        'projects.project_name', //display project name instead of project id
       // 'Assign_task_to',
        //'tasksemp.Employee_ID',
        [
            'attribute' => 'Assign_task_to',
            'format' => 'raw',
            'value' => $employes,
        ],
        'start_date',
        'due_date',
        'priotiy_level',
        'upload_documents',
    ],
]) ?>
```

But now the error says unexpected end of file.

Comment: You should not put such logic (making SQL queries to fill `$employees` variable) in view, it's a job for model or separate component. View is only responsible for display and formatting. This violates MVC principle.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

DetailView doesn't allow closure for the value because there is no need for it since DetailView operates on single model (doesn't iterate on many models like GridView).

Your first approach is totally bad because you try to push some code between the array elements. Second approach is ok but no closure allowed here.

Simply just take the code that is the body of your `function ($model)` (of course without the `return` part) and put it above the `<?= DetailView::widget(...` and then use the `$employes` variable for the value inside.

```
[
    'attribute' => 'Assign_task_to',
    'format' => 'raw',
    'value' => $employes,
],
```

Comment: I tried that but another error comes. Unexpected end of file.

Comment: I told you to use just the body of function, not the whole function.

Comment: I tried that too. But still unexpected end of file..

Comment: Paste you code in the question above.

Comment: foreach loop is not closed.

Comment: Yess!! Your right! Thanks a lot! And it works great now! Thank you Bizley!

Answer (score 0):

You can use custom functions to get a value in DetailView.

Use call_user_func() to achieve this:

```
<?= \yii\widgets\DetailView::widget([
    'model' => $yourModel,
    'attributes' => [
        [
            'label' => 'Your label',
            'value' => call_user_func(function ($model) {
                // do what you like
                // return your value;
            }, $yourModel),
        ],
        // more attributes
    ]
]); ?>
```